# Is it still possible to create a web application using the .NET Core 2.0 template that only works with full .NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Back when ASP.NET Core 1.0,1.1 were out Microsoft had two separate templates to create a .NET Core Web application:

**Something like:**

.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) - Windows, Linux, MacOS
.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) - Windows only

Is it possible to use the new ASP.NET Core 2.0 Template with only the .NET Framework? I don't see a template for it anymore and I tried the following but it is not working:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I basically created a new .NET Core 2.0 web application and changed TargetFramework to net461 and I am getting all kinds of errors saying:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.3 is not compatible with .NETFramework
>   v4.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In left dropdown you can select .NET Framework:

[image]

and you have ASP.NET Core with target .NET Framework 4.6.1:

[image]

Comment: I didn't even notice this. Thank you! I thought System.Transactions was supposed to work in .NET Core 2.0? I find myself rolling back yet again because TransactionScope does not work the same as it does when referencing the basic .NET Framework System.Transactions dll.

Comment: check [.NET API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=System.Transactions&view=netcore-2.0)